# How to monitor long calculations?

Tags: user-interface, matlab, iteration, printf

I would like to set up a counter that informs me about a long iterative computation (e.g. in `for`).

*Is it possible to set up this counter in a way that when it is updated on screen, it replaces the previous value?*

That is, printing the iterator variable of a `for` is not ok, since Matlab either prints it into a new line, or after the previous value, but after 10000 iterations the screen would be filled either way. Also, I would like to update the counter in each turn.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
fprintf('\n')
for i=1:15
    fprintf([repmat('\b', 1, length(num2str(i-1))) '%d'], i)
    pause(0.1)
end
fprintf('\n')
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `\b` to print a backspace character.  e.g.:

```
for i=1:10
    fprintf(1, '\b%d', i);
end
```

Comment: …but if you are counting to 11, it fails!

Comment: @Simon: You should just make 10 louder, and make that the top number.

Comment: That was me, I didn't get the "make 10 louder". Can you explain?

Comment: @Simon: It's a [Spinal Tap](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EbVKWCpNFhY) reference.  I was assuming that extending this technique to support longer digit strings would be a trivial exercise for the reader...

Comment: And how can I programmatically create a string array of _n_ backspaces? This does not work: `for i = 1:4 del(i) = '\b'; end`.

Comment: @IstvánZachar: To create an array of anything repeated several times, use `repmat`.  `repmat('\b', 1, n)`.

Answer (score 5):

I made this function a while ago, it draws a nice ascii progress bar. Basically the same idea as the other two answers to your question, but a bit more packaged-up

```
function progressbar(percent, N, init, extrastr)
% Draws a progress bar in the matlab command prompt. Useful for lengthly
% calculations using for loops
%
% Arguments:
%   - percent:  A number between 0 and 1
%   - N:        how many characters wide the bar should be
%   - init:     (optional; default false) true or false; whether or not
%               this is the first time calling the progressbar function for
%               your current bar.
%   - extrastr: (optional; default char(10)) An extra string to append to
%               the progress bar. Things will go screwy at the command
%               console if this string changes length from call to call of
%               progressbar.
%
% Outputs:
%
% Usage Example:
%
%   for k=1:1000
%       progressbar(k/1000,50,k==1,sprintf('\n We are are on number%4d\n', k));
%       % fake a computation
%       pause(0.05);
%   end
%

    if nargin < 3
        init = 0;
    end
    if nargin < 4
        extrastr = char(10);
    end

    percent = min(max(real(percent),0),1);

    done = round(N*percent);
    done_str = '*'*ones(1, done);
    left_str = '-'*ones(1, N-done);
    bar = sprintf(['||' done_str left_str '|| %3d'],round(percent*100));

    erase = [];
    if ~init
        % use backspace characters to erase the previously drawn bar
        erase = ['' char(8)*ones(1,length(bar)+length(extrastr)+1)];
    end

    fprintf([erase bar '%s' extrastr], '%');
    drawnow;

end
```

If your for loop is enormous, and each pass is short, it will add a lot of overhead computation time, so only call it every 100 loop iterations, or as need be.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the [waitbar()](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/waitbar.html) function. It is a bit slow, but looks nice.

Answer (score 3):

No matter what style of waitbar you are going to use, I suggest defining an interface of waitbars, and implementing it.

```
 classdef IWaitBar
       methods(Abstract)
            GoToPos(positionPercent)
       end
 end
```

Thus, you get loose coupling between the function that calculates and the GUI drawing.

In this way you can:

- Change the implementation of any `WaitBar` without modifying the calculating function.
- Add more `WaitBar`s easily, and switch them on demand
- Write an empty `WaitBar` in cases you don't want to show anything.